# JNI Java From C Memory Leak

Tags: java-native-interface

It seems that following code is leaking memory. I checked the JVM memory utilization and it is not freeing up memory after subsequent calls. When I just run the Java as standalone it works fine for multiple calls and keeps deallocating memory just fine.

I would really appreciate any help.

```
jobjectArray my_obj = (jobjectArray) env->CallObjectMethod(cls, mid, qstr, pstr);

length = env->GetArrayLength(my_obj);
//printf("\nArray Length = %d \n", length);

char result[256]; 
const char *cstr;
int numberOfCharsInThisRow = 0;


array1 = (char **)malloc(length * sizeof(char *));
/*Check if pointer is null, if not then free its memory first*/

for(int i=0; i< length ; i++){
    cstr = env->GetStringUTFChars((jstring)env->GetObjectArrayElement(my_obj,i), 0); 

    numberOfCharsInThisRow = std::strlen(cstr)+1;


    *(array1+i)=(char *)malloc(numberOfCharsInThisRow * sizeof(char)); 

    std::strcpy(result, cstr);
    std::strcpy(*(array1+i),result);


    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars((jstring)env->GetObjectArrayElement(my_obj,i), cstr);
        }
    env->DeleteLocalRef(my_obj); 
}

    //printf("\n\nDestroy JVM\n\n");
    //jvm->DestroyJavaVM();

}
```

void libdeallocatememory(char **array1,int length)
{
    //printf("Free Array memory \n");

```
for (int j=0 ;j <length ;j ++)
{
    free(array1+j);
}

free(array1);
```

}

Comment: I assume you are freeing the pointers you allocated at some point of time and this isnt the leak you are talking about

Comment: Hello, no there are no calls to free the pointers, isnt ReleaseStringUTFChars and DeleteLocalRef taking care of it? I would appreciate it if you would please tell me which pointers I need to free

Answer (score 1):

You should free the array1 pointers once you are done with them. What does this function do in reality? From the functionality I understood, you are copying from the java to a c pointer. What happens next? By calling ReleaseStringUTF, you are notifying the JVM that it isnt being used in native and so can be GCed when required
 Think I have found the problem. Releasing Code should be something like

```
for (int j=0 ;j<length; j++  )
{
    free(array1[j]);
}

free(array1);
```

The initial allocation should be `array1 = (char **)malloc(length * sizeof(int *));`
The difference is `int*` instead of `char*`. This is because this array is just an array of pointers. Pointer size is int. The next level is in the loop where you allocate memory for your strings. It should be `array1[i] = (char *)malloc(numberOfCharsInThisRow * sizeof(char));`
That means initially you allocated an array of pointers. Now for each element of that arary, you are allocating the memory to hold its own string. I think even `*(array1+i)` will work, but I find this more easy to read. So when you free, first you free the individual array elements you allocated, and then the entire array which you allocated initially. As an example, take a look at your current deallocate function. There is no difference between the free when j=0 and the last free. I am surprised you are not getting any crashes.
Take a look at http://c-faq.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx9b.html

Also try the following  `jstring myString =env->GetObjectArrayElement(my_obj,i)`; Use myString to get the UTFChars, Then call  `env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(mystring, cstr)`

Comment: Hi, array1 is being freed after it is being used. Here is how array1 is being freed. The function is a wrapper to a Java method that returns result of an SQL call as an array.

Comment: Hi, array1 is being freed after it is being used. Here is how array1 is being freed I edited the main post. The function is a wrapper to a Java method that returns result of an SQL call as an array. What we noticed that if we remove the call of mallocing array1, it still increases JVM heap size so this leads us to think that ReleaseStringUTF is not releasing memory. Would appreciate any help

Comment: Hello, I freeing the array1 like you mentioned, problem still persists, I wonder if it has to do with ReleaseStringUTF not releasing memory or the way we are copying over to c pointer has issues.

Comment: Hi, we were able to solve the problem we had to put `jstring myString =env->GetObjectArrayElement(my_obj,i)` and then `env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(mystring, cstr)` and also we had to delete local reference `env->DeleteLocalRef(mystring);` and it worked and now it is releasing memory just fine. Thank you very much!